# I want to make dictionary from csv file then add new keys with value equal to sum or values of other existing keys then perform operations on them

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, read.csv

Each dictionary must have the following keys:
“Last_name” - the student last name; a string
“First_name” - the student first name; a string
“ID” – the student ID; a string
“Projects” - a list containing the students’ three project scores. Make sure that these
scores are converted to integers.
“Tests” - a list containing the students’ three test scores. Make sure that these scores are
converted to integers.
Insert three new keys into each dictionary in each of the three lists:

- “Project Total” - an integer, its value will be the sum of the three project scores for that
  student
- “Test Total” - an integer, its value will be the sum of the three test scores for that
  students.
- “Grade” - a string. Its value will be a single letter that represents the student’s grade for
  the class. The total possible number of points is 640. To calculate the letter grade, divide
  the student’s total points, from column 10, by 640. If this is greater than or equal to 90%,
  enter an “A” in column 11. Greater than or equal to 80% but less than 90% gets a “B” in
  column 11. Greater than or equal to 70% but less than 80% gets a “C”; greater than or
  equal to 60% but less than 70% gets a “D”; and less than 60% gets an “F” in column 11.
  this code gives list of dictionary as [{'Student_last_name': 'Sarnik', 'student_first_name': 'Vatela', 'student_ID': '11205', 'project': '48', 'test': '57'}, {'Student_last_name': 'Mare', 'student_first_name': 'Henry', 'student_ID': '11206', 'project': '49', 'test': '66'}, {'Student_last_name': 'Staldo', 'student_first_name': 'Bracky', 'student_ID': '11207', 'project': '57', 'test': '75'}, {'Student_last_name': 'Brono', 'student_first_name': 'Haitel', 'student_ID': '11208', 'project': '53', 'test': '56'}]
  how i can add “Projects” - a list containing the students’ three project scores. and then add new key “Project Total” - an integer, its value will be the sum of the three project scores for that
  student
  my code

  ```
    '''
    Fall_2026_list=[]
    file_path = 'Fall_2026.csv'
    input_file = csv.DictReader(open(file_path))

    for row in input_file:
        Fall_2026_list.append(row)
    print(Fall_2026_list)
    '''
  ```

Comment: what have you tried so far and where are you stuck ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import csv
header1 = ["Student_last_name", "student_first_name", "student_ID","project1", 
"project1", "project3", "test1", "test2", "test3"]
data1 = [
    ['Sarnik', 'Vatela', 11205,67, 75, 48, 79, 74, 57],
    ['Mare', 'Henry', 11206,34, 50, 49, 64, 39, 66]
]
with open('Fall_2026.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header1)
    writer.writerows(data1)    
Fall_2026_list=[]
file_path = 'Fall_2026.csv'
input_file = csv.DictReader(open(file_path))
for row in input_file:
    Fall_2026_list.append(row)
print(Fall_2026_list)